# How to not count certain strings in a text document word counter program

Tags: python

For my program I successfully managed to make it count the words but it counts the " -- " in the document as a word too and I want my program to not count what is in quotes as a word. I'm coming up at 277 words when it is supposed to be 272.

```
infile = open("Gettysburg.txt", "r")
data = infile.readlines()
nwords = 0
lines = 0
nchars = 0
for line in data:
    words = line.split()
    lines += 1
    nwords += len(words)
    nchars += len(line)
print("Jake's word calculator.")
print('The number of words is', nwords)
```

Comment: `nwords += len([i for i in words if i != "--"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
nwords += len([i for i in words if i != "--"])
```

This builds a new list from the `words` list. Only words that do not equal "--" will go into this new list. Then it gets the length of the new list with `len()`.

Here's an alternate way to do it:

```
nwords += len(words) - words.count("--")
```

Comment: Thanks for the info and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

```
infile = open("Gettysburg.txt", "r")
data = infile.readlines()
nwords = 0
lines = 0
nchars = 0
for line in data:
    line += 1
    wordswithlines = line.split()
    for i in wordswithlines:
        if i == "--":
           print("-- found") #if you are using python 2.7 use print "-- found"
        else:
           words=words+i
    nwords += len(words)
    nchars += len(line)
print("Jake's word calculator.")
print("The number of words is" nwords)
```

Comment: It's giving me an invalid syntax error in line 5 on the "$i"